# Jetty (mis)configuration: it wont respond from an external machine... why?

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, amazon-ec2, jetty

I installed jetty on an ubuntu 11 machine by

```
sudo apt-get install jetty
```

afterwards I configured the context, the war file and the NO_START variable. All works OK when I test it on the same machine, e.g.

```
curl http://localhost:8080/
```

However, when I try to connect from an external machine, it just doesn't answer.
I tried this both on a virtual machine on a  Win 7 host, and on Amazon EC2.

thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure this is not an firewall issue. Maybe 8080 port is closed by firewall.

Also try add line into  file /etc/default/jetty :

```
JETTY_HOST=0.0.0.0
```

See [similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/156687/configuring-jetty-to-accept-connections-from-all-hosts-on-ubuntu-lucid)

Answer (score 1):

In EC2 realm, the default open port is usually 80. You need to go to your EC2 console, see the SecurityGroup associated with the machine, and add the port `8080` open  for whole word i.e. `0.0.0.0/0`. And you should be all set.

Comment: thanks. tried that and didn't work. also, my virtual machine behaved exactly the same

Comment: so you opened port `8080` and tried `http://public_dns_of_the_machine:8080/`, could you try `nmap` to see if the `8080` is actually open. What response do you get when you `curl` from outside?